# Cannot read property of undefined - small random quote app bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I've been trying to build a random quote app. So far I have this: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-heyrovsky-4msq4?file=/src/App.js

In short, I fetch a quotes list from an API, and then try to display the quotes and the authors when the page loads, and every time I press the button. But there's a problem.

```js
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/natebass/b0a548425a73bdf8ea5c618149fe1fce/raw/f4231cd5961f026264bb6bb3a6c41671b044f1f4/quotes.json"
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((quotes) => setAllQuotes(quotes));
  }, []);

  const [allQuotes, setAllQuotes] = useState([]);
  // this is the array of all quote objects
  const [quoteIndex, setQuoteIndex] = useState(0);
  //this is the number used as array index
  const [text, setText] = useState("This app is Broken");
  // this is the quote text to be displayed
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState("Press set twice");
  // this is the quote author to be displayed 
  const [chosenQuote, setChosenQuote] = useState({});
  // this is the selected quote object 
  function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuotes.length);
  }

  let handleClick = () => {
    setQuoteIndex(randomNumber);
    setText(chosenQuote.quote);
    setAuthor(chosenQuote.author);
    setChosenQuote(allQuotes[quoteIndex]);
    // this is supposed to choose a random object within the array, and set text and quote state to the quote and author properties of the selected object
  };

  console.log(chosenQuote);

 
  return (
    <div id="quote-container">
      <div id="quote-box">
        <h1 id="text">{text}</h1>
        <p id="author">{author}</p>

        {/*when I press the button, it loads the next quote, but displays the previous quote, hence why nothing displays on first click */}
        <button onClick={handleClick}>New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If I try to load the quotes while the page loads, it gives me the "Cannot read property(quote) of undefined" error. If I try to load the quotes after the page has loaded by editing the javascript, then it works, but it displays the messages from the previously loaded object, not the current one. You can see the behavior in codesandbox.

So, can someone explain to me why this is happening and how I can fix it so that the app displays the quotes properly on load and then changes on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because setState from useState hook is asynchronous so you can do something like:

```
 setChosenQuote(allQuotes[quoteIndex]);
    setText(allQuotes[quoteIndex].quote);
    setAuthor(allQuotes[quoteIndex].author);
```

Comment: That fixed the problem of the previous quote displaying instead of the current one. Could you also explain to me how I can change my useEffect() so that it also loads the quotes correctly when the app mounts? Sorry for simple questions, I'm just starting out with React and this synchronicity is going to take some time to get used to.

Comment: your useEffect is correct but to fix the issue while your page is loading you can add a conditional render for your all container or only your button like this: 
`{allQuotes.length && <button onClick={handleClick}>New Quote</button>}`. the button will only be render when your allQuotes will be fill

Comment: I thought about it more and decided to make a different alteration and now it loads properly. Though now I have another bug and I think I'll open another thread for it.

What I did was I changed the second .then statement to avoid all async issues like this 
`.then(quotes => {(setAllQuotes(quotes))
            const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
            setAuthor(quotes[randNum].author)
            setText(quotes[randNum].quote)`